# python3 how to find out which line in apply_async target function caused error when error_callback is applied

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Using python 3.4

I have a target function that fails and apply_async calls my error callback function instead of my callback function.

The problem is that the exception captured and sent to the error_callback is not helpful and I can't figure out *where* the error in the target function occurs.

My error callback

```
  def error_callback(self,e):
    print('error_callback()',e)
    # tested one of these at a time
    traceback.print_exc()
    traceback.print_last()
    traceback.print_stack()
```

And the traceback outputs

print_exc

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/traceback.py", line 125, in _iter_chain
    context = exc.__context__
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__context__'
```

print_last

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/traceback.py", line 262, in print_last
    raise ValueError("no last exception")
  ValueError: no last exception
```

print_stack

```
  File "./relative/path/to/my/script.py", line 71, in traceback
    traceback.print_stack()
```

I'd have to confess that I ain't really comfortable with the traceback library and how to use it but it seems to me that it's not possible to use traceback in this case?

What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `traceback` functions you're calling are all expecting to get the exception info from `sys.exec_info`, which is where exception information is usually stored while an exception is being caught. However, since the actual exception in your case came from a child process, they're not finding any exception information when you call them in the parent process.

You need to use extract the relevant information from the Exception object `e` that you received from the child process. Try using `traceback.print_exception` with appropriate arguments:

```
traceback.print_exception(type(e), e, e.__traceback__)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I can't figure out where the error in the target function occurs.

Here is an example of what you can do:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def do_stuff(num):
    if False:
        x = 10
    else: 
        x = 20

    result = 5/(2 - num)  #Line 9
    return result 

def success_handler(result):
    print('success')

def error_handler(e):
    print('error')
    print(dir(e), "\n")
    print("-->{}<--".format(e.__cause__))

with mp.Pool(2) as my_pool:
    results =  [
        my_pool.apply_async(
            do_stuff, 
            args=(i,),
            callback=success_handler, 
            error_callback=error_handler
       ) 
       for i in range(3)
    ]


    try:
        for result_obj in results:
            print("result is: {}".format(result_obj.get()))
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print("Oh, boy.  This is the second time I've seen this error.")


--output:--
success
success
result is: 2.5
result is: 5.0
error
['__cause__', '__class__', '__context__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__suppress_context__', '__traceback__', 'args', 'with_traceback'] 

-->
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "1.py", line 10, in do_stuff
    result = 5/(2 - num)  #Line 9
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
"""<--
Oh, boy.  This is the second time I've seen this error.
```

Note the line numbers of the target function in the error message.

I don't really understand the purpose of the `error_callback` because after calling the error_callback, multiprocessing reraises the error, so you have to catch it anyway.  I guess the error_calback must be used for doing process specific cleanup.

Comment: I didn't know about e.__cause__ `def error_callback(self,e):
    print('error_callback()',e.__cause__)`  gives the same traceback as traceback.print_exception(type(e), e, e.__traceback__)!

Comment: Regarding the purpose of error_callback. I'm no expert so I'm not sure I understand your question correctly or the purpose of error_callback, but if you don't have the error_callback and the error occurs outside of your try/except blocks in your target function then the error is never captured even if raised. In my case it results in my script seemingly freezing or continuing with weird behavior and have to be interrupted with ctrl+c. So I see error_callback as an "except" handler ie try: target function except error_callback as e: (handle e). That's how I see it/use it.

Comment: @user1267259,  *I see error_callback as an "except" handler*--but it doesn't work that way.  In my example, if I remove the try/except around `get()`, the error_callback does not catch the error.

Comment: As far as I can tell I don't have that problem. And the only difference from my code that I see in your code is, you use return values and later result_obj.get() them. Does it work for you if you run `for i in range(3): my_pool.apply_async(...)`? (instead of result = [list comp] and remove the try/except with the result_obj.get()